# Livechat system with push notifications (php)

Tags: php, server-push, livechat

im developing a dating site, which includes a livechat system where people can chat in private conversations (like facebook chat, or the badoo message system).

What is the best approach for a live chat? I'm thinking about a push system. Do I have to store the chat log in a mysql table, or can I use plain log files for that?

Our servers run PHP 5.3 on CentOS 5.3. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

I personally would not like to start from scratch on a chat system. Have you had a look at Mibew (http://mibew.org/)? I have used it on several projects and modified it each time as required. Its open source and relativly easy to modify.

Comment: I'm downloading it right now. Have you tested it with hundreds of users connected at the same time?

Comment: Mmm not more than 3 or so at a time but it would depend on how you implement it and the server spec. Are you planning a public chat system (all site users can chat to each other) or or private chat system (2 users)? Mibew is actually meant as a support system (2 people at a time) but I have modified it to have multiple users online at the same time. I never had the need for hundreds at a time though so remains to be seen how it will perform. I guess it would depend on your server bandwidth and capacity at the end of the day. It might not be perfect for your needs but does have the basics.

Comment: It will always be a 2 users private chat. Always. But of course there will be more than 100 people chatting with eachother (if the site grows fast, then it could be 1000 users, and so on). I'll try to adapt the same implementation to my system in order to test it. Thanks!

Comment: @Zappa What modifications did you do? Do you have any project where wee can see these mods?